# the redux state didn t change after trying updating

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, state, redux-toolkit

*res in then gets me an object but still can t update it redux state*
i created account the when it returns me the value ***res*** .i can console it but i can t save it in the redux state

```
const initialState = {
  user: {},
};

export const Auth_Slice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loginWithEmail: async (state, action) => {
      await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        action.payload.email,
        action.payload.password
      ).then((res) => {
        state.user = res;
        console.log(res.user);
      });
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create `async actions` and use extraReducers in create slice.

```
export const createUserWithEmailAndPassword = createAsyncThunk(
  "createUserWithEmailAndPassword",
  async (payload) => {
    const response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        payload.email,
        payload.password
      );
    return response;
  }
);

const initialState = {
  status: "",
  user: {},
};

export const Auth_Slice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(createUserWithEmailAndPassword.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(createUserWithEmailAndPassword.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "idle";
        state.user = action.payload?.user ?? {};
      });
  }
})
```

;